# Вложенность в sass?

Tags: css, sass, frontend, gulp-sass

Можно ли при компиляции в SASS убрать вложенность?
Или писать код без вложенности? На данный момент это выглядит вот так:

```
.main-page__main-header .main-header__wrapper .main-header__column .main-
 header__menu .main-header__item .main-header__link {}
```

Верстается многостраничный сайт, и нужно чтобы все стили были отдельно и все страницы обращались к одному файлу.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли при компиляции в SASS убрать вложенность?

Вы имеете ввиду при трансляции из SASS в CSS? Как вы себе, интересно, это представляете. Хотите всю эту цепочку преобразовывать в отдельный класс?

Если нужно, чтобы все стили были отдельно, то прописывайте их в отдельных файлах и подключайте в единый. И уже этот единый файл подключайте к каждой странице сайта.

Если Вас конкретно вложенность такая пугает, то попробуйте, например, пользоваться полной методологией БЭМ. Это должно ускорить Вашу многостраничную разработку.

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду при компиляции из sass в css.

Comment: @pokemonjke Вам же по сути все равно на эти вложенности - стили редактируются в SASS, а для многоразового использования тех же блоков стилей можно наследование применять или локально создавать новые классы.